# why could access url using curl but faild in the google chrome broswer

Tags: nginx, http

I am config the localhost url in the nginx on macOS like this:

```
➜  nginx git:(master) cat conf.d/reddwarf-admin.conf
server {
        listen 8083;
        server_name admin.reddwarf.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }
        location ^~ /service/ {
            proxy_pass  https://admin.example.top/;
             proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

then config the local doman in the `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   admin.reddwarf.com
```

get the web using command in terminal like this:

```
curl http://admin.reddwarf.com:8083
```

get the html success. the next step, get the url from google chrome, shows error:

```
This page isn’t workingadmin.reddwarf.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 502
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to make it could access from both terminal and google chrome? this is my macOS dns configuration:

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/resolv.conf
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 192.168.31.1
```

I could access the port using local network `192.168.x.x` ip address.

Comment: wild guess: different DNS setup, broken AAAA records, misconfigured proxies either for curl or in Chrome. You'll need to do a bit more debugging on your own!

Comment: how to know my google chrome dns and macos terminal dns? @MarcusMüller

Comment: Most likely is chrome is ignoring your hosts entries. Looks like there is a resolution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1299337)